# Как организовать переключение сайта на резервный сервер?

Tags: сервер, хостинг, dns, домен, резервное-копирование

У нас есть основной сайт - большой портал с тысячами страниц, личными кабинетами, которыми пользуются тысячи людей, с кучей информацией для клиентов, внутренней системой CRM для наших сотрудников, а также десятками почтовыми аккаунтами. Всё это работает на одном домене и собрано вместе - т.е. система монолитная, переделывать что-то уже не судьба как говорится.

Совсем недавно случилась авария у нашего хостинг провайдера и наша VPS'ка умерла на большой срок.

Естественно мы продумали систему основной - резервный сервер. Зашли в панель управления регистратора домена и изменили NS-сервера.

Через несколько (довольно много) часов сайт заработал на резервном хостинге и всё стало нормально!

Вопрос такой: как можно реализовать систему таким образом, чтобы можно было быстро и оперативно переключать наш домен с одного хостинга на другой (с основного сервера на резервный)? Вариант запасного сервера у одного и того же хостинга провайдера не совсем хороший вариант для нас - один раз мы уже так связались с одной компаний, в итоге не рабочими были оба сервера (у них были проблемы с магистралью).

Answer (score 2):

Записи у регистраторов доменов из базы в бой применяются не сразу, а обычно по расписанию. Плюс к этому dns-сервера кешируют адреса NS (собственно как и все остальные адреса). Это несет большие задержки в изменение NS серверов.

Разнесите NS сервера с остальными сервисами. Поддержку DNS много где предлагают и даже бесплатно. Те же регистраторы доменов предлагат услуги (правда обычно платные). Если у вас будет собственный резервный сервер в интернете - то можно и на нем поднять полноценный DNS который в рабочей ситуации будет выдавать ответы с ip рабочего сервера. А в случае аварийной ситуации надо менять записи не у регистратора (NS) а в своих DNS поменять основные A записи. Максимальное время переключения при этом составит тот TTL (время кеширования записи на серверах в интернете), который вы укажете в описании зоны.

Только надо обязательно отладить оповещение мастер DNS слейвов и оперативных забор зоны. Либо вообще поднять все DNS в режиме мастера и менять при аварии записи на каждом по отдельности. Правда несколько мастеров затрудняют поддержу, потому как все изменения в зоне надо всегда руками производить на всех серверах.

Вариант номер 2 (для web):

На основном и резервном серверах обращение к контент-серверам организовать через прокси (nginx), причем прокси на резервом сервере редиректит запросы на основной контент-сервер. В аварийной ситуации он переключается на собственный контент-сервер. Прокси можно опять же поднять несколько.

Comment: "Разнесите NS сервера с остальными сервисами" - простите, а что именно вы имеете в виду здесь под словами сервисы?

Comment: Я имею ввиду держать их не там же где основной сервер, отвечающий на web запросы и т.п. Желательно что бы у NS серверов были гораздо меньшие шансы упасть.

Comment: "Если у вас будет собственный резервный сервер в интернете - то можно и на нем поднять полноценный DNS который в рабочей ситуации будет выдавать ответы с ip рабочего сервера. " - но наряду с этим можно воспользоваться сервисом поддержки DNS со стороны нашего регистратора? ведь так? 

скажите а с работой почты на домене как будет? Я так понимаю, тоже необходимо будет быстро поменять записи в DNS для почтового сервера?

Comment: Да, я бы наверное так и сделал, поставил DNS у себя и копия что бы у регистратора держалась. Вашу то зону они думаю сразу перегрузят как только измените ее. С почтой да - поменяете MX запись в зоне. Правда как вы потом будете ее синхронизировать, после оживления основной vps... Т.е. если письмо принято резерным сервером но еще не прочитано получателем то оно же должно будет потом переместится на основной сервер почты ... И если у вас письма остаются на сервере то надо что бы они синхронно были на на резерве

Comment: для нас не так страшны перебои в работе почты, как падение сайта.

Comment: итак, если подвести итоге алгоритм должен быть такой:
1) Включаем управление DNS в панели регистратора (у нас там есть такая возможность, дается бесплатно)
2) включаем управление DNS на основном и резервном хостингах? Или же это не обязательно? 
3) В случае с аварией на основном сервере, нам нужно будет поменять некоторые записи в DNS у регистратора для того чтобы все запросы шли на сервер резервного хостинга?

Comment: Для веба по 2му варинату можно просто прокси взять не падающие, типа cloud flare или какой нибудь фильтрующей ddos компании. Если защита от ddos нужна, может заодно два в одном получите.

Comment: Теоретически регистратор от же может упасть. У них конечно резервирование обязано быть очень солидным (иначе бы они не смогли получить статус регистратора). И в любом случае лучше когда есть DNS совершенно на других каналах нежели идут до регитратора. Блекаут в Москве показал, что и регистраторы могут быть не доступны. Только обязательно проверьте, когда зона будет у регистратора, внесите какую нибудь запись в домен и убедитесь что регистратор сразу отвечать на нее начал и потом меняйте ip и смотрите что бы то же сразу начал давать новые ответы, а то вдруг он эти записи не сразу в бой отдает

Comment: интересно а бывают такие регистраторы, у которых все это дело автоматизировано, т.е. мы как бы забиваем сразу все необходимые записи в DNS для основного и резервного варианта, а потом имеем возможность одной кнопкой быстро переключать с одного на другой.

Comment: никогда не видел. но тут я не спец, никогда не пользовался сторонними DNS :) Единственное, может у них есть возможность загрузить ваш файл зоны целиком, тогда вы просто разные файлы для разных случаев держите. Для собственных DNS серверов так можно и поступить.

Comment: А еще у них бывают API. Кстати вот еще http://habrahabr.ru/post/203292/   И еще можно покопать в стороны DDNS, но с этим я никогда не работал. Но на сколько я понимаю после какой то авторизации по ключам вы можете на DDNS менять инфу прямо по протоколу DNS. просто делается какой то скрипт который сам по DDNS на всех серверах меняет что нужно

Comment: а что означает собственные DNS сервера? Здесь же речь идет не о панели управления DNS регистратора? Это такая отдельная услуга? Которую где-то можно приобрести отдельно от регистратора? Или же регистратор может продавать такую услугу?

Comment: Собственные - это когда у вас стоит например named и поддерживает зону, которую вы ему описали в настройках. А у регистратора только NS

Comment: У меня например зоны держатся на моем же сервере, своим named'ом. А вторичный DNS на моей старой работе, у них там канал интернета никак с моими не связанный. Я просто договорился, я держу у себя копию их зоны, а они у меня свою.

Comment: т.е. в панели управления доменом нужно будет прописать NS-адреса какого-то стороннего сервера управления DNS? а на нём уже настраивать DNS-записи указывающие на хостинг? А то я уже запутался во всём этом )

Comment: Да. Вообще DNS работает так: у регистратора лежат _только_ NS записи, которые показывают какие сервера могут отвечать на вопросы по этой зоне. Далее есть сами сервера отвечающие за зону. Если их негде разместить, то услугу по их поддержке берут у того же регистратора например или где либо еще

Comment: а вот вы еще написали про свой (собственный) named и вторичный DNS и копию зон. Получается у вас в настройках домен указаны NS-сервера вашего собственного DNS named? И если с вашим собственным что-то случится то как переключится на копию зон? менять NS-сервера у регистратора?

Comment: У регистратора всегда прописаны 2 NS и на основной сервер и на копию. Копия - это вторичный dns сервер, в принципе он равноценен с основным, запросы в рабочем режиме всегда идут и на тот и на другой, потому как запрашивающие dns-сервера всегда выбирают одну из NS записей случайным образом. Если один NS не доступен то они стучатся на следующий. Если у меня будет долгий простой, я просто в копии поменяю A записи. NS менять не буду.

Comment: нашёл еще такое вот решение: http://habrahabr.ru/post/177145/

Comment: Но это решение именно для _параллельно работающих серверов_ потому как запросы, как я говорил выше, будут приходить случайным образом на обе DNS, следовательно и web запросы пойдут на обе сервера одновременно. Если web у вас это позволяет и коллизий не будет - то отличное решение. примерно что же, что просто в зону написать несколько A записей